# Create then Update - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, update-attributes

I have a set of parameters below that are submitted through a form

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pyMkh1eJ7WxYC978XKjdsyGOeGDvi6RTIOSGb9KMqkc=", "link"=>{"category_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"", "url"=>"yahoo.com "}, "type"=>"html", "original_url"=>"http://yahoo.com", "url"=>"http://www.yahoo.com/", "title"=>"Yahoo!", "description"=>"Welcome to Yahoo!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and information.", "favicon_url"=>"http://www.yahoo.com/favicon.ico", "provider_url"=>"http://www.yahoo.com", "provider_display"=>"www.yahoo.com", "provider_name"=>"Yahoo", "safe"=>"true", "html"=>"", "thumbnail_url"=>"", "object_type"=>"link", "image_url"=>"", "category_id"=>"1"}
```

I want to create a new "links" record in the links model, which belongs to the categories model. My "create" action in the links controller looks like this

```
  def create
    @category = Category.find_by_id(params[:category_id])
    @link = @category.links.build(params[:link])
    @link.user_id = current_user.id
    respond_to do |format|
        if @link.save
            links_attributes = params.slice(:original_url, :title, :description, :favicon_url, :provider_url, :provider_display, :thumbnail_url, :object_type)
            @link.update_attributes(links_attributes)
        else 

        end
    end     
  end
```

If I just did @link.save without the update attributes, it only saves comment, url and category id.  However, the above creates 2 records, one comment, url and category_id and another with all of the data.

How can I make sure this creates just one record, with all of the information?

**UPDATE**
If I could just create the record with the 3 parameters, then update it with the remaining parameters (links_attributes), I would be fine with that...just not sure how to do it.

This is the output I get when submitting:

```
Started POST "/categories/1/links" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-11 12:43:44 -0500
Processing by LinksController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pyMkh1eJ7WxYC978XKjdsyGOeGDvi6RTIOSGb9KMqkc=", "link"=>{"category_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"", "url"=>"bloomberg.com "}, "type"=>"html", "original_url"=>"http://bloomberg.com", "url"=>"http://www.bloomberg.com/", "title"=>"Business, Financial & Economic News, Stock Quotes", "description"=>"Bloomberg is a premier site for business and financial market news. It delivers world economic news, stock futures, stock quotes, & personal finance advice.", "favicon_url"=>"http://www.bloomberg.com/favicon.ico", "provider_url"=>"http://www.bloomberg.com", "provider_display"=>"www.bloomberg.com", "provider_name"=>"Bloomberg", "safe"=>"true", "html"=>"", "thumbnail_url"=>"http://www.bloomberg.com/image/is2KySnyVWmA.jpg", "object_type"=>"link", "image_url"=>"", "category_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "links" ("category_id", "comment", "created_at", "description", "favicon_url", "object_type", "original_url", "points", "profile_link", "provider_display", "provider_url", "thumbnail", "thumbnail_url", "title", "updated_at", "url", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["category_id", "1"], ["comment", ""], ["created_at", Fri, 11 Jan 2013 17:43:

Started POST "/categories/1/links" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-11 12:43:44 -0500
Processing by LinksController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"pyMkh1eJ7WxYC978XKjdsyGOeGDvi6RTIOSGb9KMqkc=", "link"=>{"category_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"", "url"=>""}, "commit"=>"Post", "category_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSE44 UTC +00:00], ["description", "Bloomberg is a premier site for business and financial market news. It delivers world economic news, stock futures, stock quotes, & personal finance advice."], ["favicon_url", "http://www.bloomberg.com/favicon.ico"], ["object_type", "link"], ["original_url", "http://bloomberg.com"], ["points", nil], ["profile_link", nil], ["provider_display", "www.bloomberg.com"], ["provider_url", "http://www.bloomberg.com"], ["thumbnail", nil], ["thumbnail_url", "http://www.bloomberg.com/imRT INTO "links" ("category_id", "comment", "created_at", "description", "favicon_url", "object_type", "original_url", "points", "profile_link", "provider_display", "provider_url", "thumbnail", "thumbnail_url", "title", "updated_at", "url", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["category_id", "1"], ["comment", ""], ["created_at", Fri, 11 Jan 2013 17:43:44 UTC +00:00], ["description", nil], ["favicon_url", nil], ["object_type", nil], ["original_url", nil], ["points", nil], ["profile_link", nil], ["provider_display", nil], ["provider_url", nil], ["thumbnail", nil], ["thumbnail_url", nil], ["title", nil], ["updated_at", Fri, 11 Jan 2013 17:43:44 UTC +00:00], ["url", ""], ["user_id", 1]]
   (1.1ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered links/create.js.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 3.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
age/is2KySnyVWmA.jpg"], ["title", "Business, Financial & Economic News, Stock Quotes"], ["updated_at", Fri, 11 Jan 2013 17:43:44 UTC +00:00], ["url", "bloomberg.com "], ["user_id", 1]]
   (2.5ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered links/create.js.erb (0.0ms)
```

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for([@category, @category.links.build], :remote => true, :class => "form-horizontal") do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :category_id, :value => params[:id] %>
    Comment: <%= f.text_field :comment %><BR>
    Link: <%= f.text_field :url %>
    <%= f.submit "Post", :class => "btn", :disable_with => '...', :id => "new_link_button" %>
<% end %>

<div class="selector" style="width:350px;margin:-30px 0px 0px 0px;"></div>
<!-- Placeholder that tells Preview where to put the loading icon-->
<div class="loading">
    <img src='http://embedly.github.com/jquery-preview/images/loading-rectangle.gif'>
</div>


<script>


$('#link_url').preview({ key:'60f1dcdf3258476794784148a6eb65e7', // Sign up for a key: http://embed.ly/pricing

      selector : {type:'rich'},
      preview : {
        submit : function(e, data){
          $.ajax({
            dataType: 'script',
            url: this.form.attr('action'),
            type: 'POST',
            data: data
          });
        },
      },
      autoplay : 0,
      maxwidth : 350,
      display : {display : 'rich'}
});

$('#new_link_button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventdevault();
    $('.new_link').submit();
    return false;
});

</script>
```

This is my routes:

```
  resources :categories, :only => [:new, :show, :create, :edit, :update] do
    resources :links, :only => [:new, :show, :create, :edit, :update]
    resources :industries, :only => [:new, :show, :create, :edit, :update]
    resources :territories, :only => [:new, :show, :create, :edit, :update]
  end
```

Comment: If links depends on categories, maybe you are saving them in the wrong order? Try saving the category one time, and i believe all the associations would be persisted.

Comment: Well, I'm not creating a new category every time...just a new link.  Links is a subset of categories...

Comment: Try to comment the `@link.update_attributes(links_attributes)` line and then see, if it still creates two records, then make sure that no other code such as callbacks (after_save, ... ) are creating the additional record.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with how your form is being constructed. As you can see in your posted parameters, `params[:link]` only includes a subset of the data you are trying to save on link:

`"link"=>{"category_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"", "url"=>"yahoo.com "}`

The rest is all at the top level of the params array:

`Parameters: {... "original_url"=>"http://yahoo.com", "url"=>"http://www.yahoo.com/", "title"=>"Yahoo!", "description"=>"Welcome to Yahoo!..." ...}`

You should look at how you're using form_for to construct your form, and make sure it's being used correctly for the additional parameters.

**Edit:**

If you can't edit the form, then you could do this in your controller:

```
@link.user_id = current_user.id
links_attributes = params.slice(:original_url, :title, :description, :favicon_url, :provider_url, :provider_display, :thumbnail_url, :object_type)
@link.attributes = links_attributes
respond_to do |format| 
   if @link.save
      ...
```

Comment: I can't change that, as the other parameters are being added through an API.  If I could create the record, then update with the right parameters, that would solve the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting them before save.

```
def create
  @link = Link.new(params[:link])
  @link.category_id = params[:category_id]
  @link.original_url = params[:original_url]
  @link.title = params[:title]
  @link.description = params[:description]
  @link.user_id = current_user.id
  # etc...
  respond_to do |format|
    if @link.save
      # do things...
    else 
      # do other things...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Well, thats odd. Maybe the action is getting called twice?

Comment: Ugh.  Not sure.  i just posted the form and code, output and and routes as well.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to call `@link.save` then `@link.update_attributes`, because `@link.update_attributes` would save `@link` in your db if it is not already there.

From the logs you posted, it seems your controller receives two post requests, this is why it creates two objects, I think the reason, is that two submits happen:
one by the form that is submitted and the other one by the ajax request inside your `$('#link_url').preview(...` code.